# Reasons for javax.mail.SendFailedException: No recipient addresses error

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

Could some one please let me know why could we get the following exception.

```
javax.mail.SendFailedException: No recipient addresses
```

Could it be because an address is null or empty? Or something else?

Comment: Offcourse :) possilities  of being incorrect recipients ,, Always try to add your stack trace here:)

Comment: No.recipients is correct. because one day before the mail was sent on the same address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/SendFailedException.html)

> This exception is thrown when the message cannot be sent.   The
>   exception includes those addresses to which the message could not be
>   sent as well as the valid addresses to which the message was sent and
>   valid addresses to which the message was not sent

Comment: This is stack trace...daily credit sending failed...javax.mail.SendFailedException: No recipient addresses
credit sending failed...javax.mail.SendFailedException: No recipient addresses
daily quota sending failed...javax.mail.SendFailedException: No recipient addresses
quota sending failed::javax.mail.SendFailedException: No recipient addresses

Comment: @RaniAgrawal what am I supposed to do with these errros? Are you trying to say that you are getting these error and need help? Show the code as well.

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14272607/edit) the stack trace into the question along with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and use code formatting on both of them.